# What does this perl line from a "bleached" file do?

Tags: perl, deobfuscation

I have some perl files which have been "bleached" (don't know if it was from ACME::Bleach, or something similar). Not being very fluent in perl, I'd like to understand what the one-liner that starts the file does to decode the whitespace that follows:

```
$_=<<'';y;\r\n;;d;$_=pack'b*',$_;$_=eval;$@&&die$@;$_
```

The rest of the file is whitespace characters, and the file is executable by itself (it's placed in a /bin directory).

[Solution], thanks to @JB.

The `pack` portion of this seems the most complex, and it took me a while to notice what was going on. Pack is taking the LSB *only* of every 8 characters, and unpacking that as a big-endian character in binary. Tabs hence become '0's, and spaces become '1's.

```
    '\t\t   \t  ' => '#'
in binary:
    00001001 00001001 00100000 00100000 00100000 00001001 00100000 0100000
every LSB:
    1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
convert from from big-endian format:
    0b00100011 == 35 == ord('#')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `$_ = << '';` reads the rest of the file into the accumulator.
- `y;\r\n;;d;` strips carriage returns and line feeds.
- `$_ = pack 'b*', $_;` converts characters to bits in `$_`, LSB first.
- `$_ = eval;` executes `$_` as Perl code.
- `$@ && die $@; $_` handles exceptions and the return code gracefully.

Comment: OK, I think it's the `pack` function that's tripping me up. Can you clarify how something like `'\t\t   \t   '` translates to `'#'`?

Comment: Sorry, looks like the raw characters still has spaces collapsed, that string should be `tab tab sp sp sp tab sp sp sp`.

Comment: `tab` is `chr(9)`, odd; `sp` is `chr(32)`, even.  So your string translates to bit sequence 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, which (LSB first) is 0x23, the ASCII code for `'#'`.  (you have an extra bit)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`unbleach.pl`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=unbleach.pl) to remove bleaching, if that's what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. It also guards against link rot.

Comment: @0A0D, Fine, fixed. I thought it went without saying in this case.

Comment: You're being voted down bc I never asked how to unbleach the file (plus unbleach.pl won't work directly on these files without some tweaks). I stated that I wanted to learn how the perl line that starts each file works.

Comment: @JimB, I already explained I was guessing at the reason for which you were asking. Very few people actually ask the question to which they actually want an answer. See [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Keep in mind that StackOverflow expects answers to be useful to future readers too. By downvoting (as oppose to not accepting the answer), you are saying that `unbleach.pl` isn't useful to anyone asking the question you asked, and I'm afraid my extensive experience at answering Perl questions shows that you're wrong.

Comment: @JimB, Even though it turned out not to be what you wanted, I shall not delete my answer because it could be still be useful to future readers. I'm disappointed you think that you think this behaviour is worth discouraging.

Comment: @ikegami - That's fine, I was only postulating as to why you were downvoted. I'm sure unbleach.pl will be helpful to someone.